# Does an src make request if the style is display:none

Tags: html, css, image, request

Just wanted to confirm. I have an image that has style="display:none;"

So does it still make an URL request? Or does it ignore the request? I need to make a request :) and not display an image :)

`<img width=1 height=1 src="http://tracker.mozo.com.au/record_impression/TravelInsurance/1/1/widget_A/1.jpg" style="display:none;">`

Comment: Pretty sure CSS is read after the HTML has been loaded.. Therefore, I am assuming that there is a request, that is then styled not to be displayed.. correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: For future reference you can easily determine this thing by using the net panel in the developer tools for the browser of your choice (or the ever-popular Firebug for Firefox).  This is something you should definitely familiarize yourself with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different browser define this differently.Check Below.
**See reference:**

> 1. [Hidden element and HTTP requests](http://www.justinmarsan.com/blog/researches/hidden-elements-and-http-requests.html)
> 2. [Technique for content specific Images.](http://css-tricks.com/techniques-for-context-specific-images/)

Yes if you are making request the system will obey it. Than if you are statically making it `display:none` it loads in container but is not shown.Talking about the DOWNLOADING part, It depends on browser type.Different browser define this differently.

Comment: That's all I need, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it makes the request. The browser reads HTML and CSS separately. The `src` attribute will set the value and the `display:none` will just hide the element.